# Regular expressions - overlapping named capture groups

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression to capture a single number as 2 different named capture groups?

For example, if I am capturing pairs of values, but sometimes there is only one value:

```
5, 5
3
2, 5
```

And I want to store the single value as both the first and second capture group, is this possible? E.g. if my groups are named firstValue and secondValue:

```
firstValue = 5, secondValue = 5
firstValue = 3, secondValue = 3
firstValue = 2, secondValue = 5
```

I guess a simplification to this question would be: Is it possible to include the same character in more than one capture group? I am currently using C# but would be interested to know if this is possible in other languages too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in *every* case, but here are a couple of tricks you can use for your example:

```
@"(?m)^(?=(?<firstValue>\d+\b))(?:\k<firstValue>, *)?(?<secondValue>\d+)\r?$"
```

The first number is captured in group `firstValue`, but because the group is inside a lookahead, the match position then returns to the beginning of the string.  If there's a second number, the first one will be followed immediately by comma. `(?:\k<firstValue>, *)?` tries to consume the number, the comma, and any trailing spaces, and `(?<secondValue>\d+)` captures the second number.

If there's only one number, `(?:\k<firstValue>, *)?` consumes nothing, which is okay because it's optional.  That leaves the match position still at the beginning of the string, so `(?<secondValue>\d+)` captures the first number again, this time in group `secondValue`.  We haven't tried to put anything else in group `firstValue`, so the number is still there, too.

Here's another approach that's less elegant but probably easier to understand:

```
@"(?m)^(?<secondValue>(?<firstValue>\d+))(?:, *(?<secondValue>\d+))?\r?$"
```

Basically the same as the other responders' solutions, but I start out by capturing the first number in *both* groups.  If there proves to be a second number, it will be captured in group `secondValue`, overwriting the value that's already there.  Group `firstValue` still contains the first number.

Comment: Ok, great. So to summarise I can either use a nested capture group (2nd example) or a positive lookahead combined with a backreference to an existing capture group (1st example).

BTW, is \r sufficient to match newlines? Would [\r\n]* be better?

Comment: Actually, the `\r?` is a workaround for a flaw in the .NET regex flavor.  `$` is supposed to match either the very end of the string or just before a line separator, as described [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#RL1.6).  In reality, the only line separators you're likely to see are `\r\n` or `\n` alone. (`\r` alone was used by older Apple operating systems, and the others I've never seen at all.)  However, .NET doesn't even go that far; the only line separator it recognizes is `\n` alone.  So it's become common practice to use `\r?$` instead of `$` in .NET regexes.

Comment: This is confirmed working (i went with the 2nd approach). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to include the same character in more than one capture
>   group?

Straight answer - **No** (Not unless you have nested capture groups). Once a character is captured or is matched, it can not be matched again.

But, if your problem is having single values sometimes, then you can rather make the second capture group optional by using the `?` quantifier.

```
(?<firstValue>\d+)(, (?<secondValue>\d+))?
```

So now we have made `, secondValue` optional. So it will match both `3, 5` and `3`.

Comment: If it were me, I would have answered "Straight answer - Yes, but only if you use nested capture groups." I think the initial No is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.. Instead you can check whether you have captured the second value.

```
var values=Regex.Matches(@"(?<fv>\d+)(,\s*(?<sv>\d+))?")
  .Cast<match>()
  .Select(m=>
    new {
      firstValue=m.Groups["fv"].Value;
      secondValue=m.Groups["sv"].Value==""?m.Groups["fv"].Value:m.Groups["sv"].Value;
    }
  );
```